# Combining AjaxOnlyAttribute and ChildActionOnlyAttribute into one action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to be able to mark an action on controller to be called both from ajax calls and via RenderAction. The problem is that both this attributes derive or implement different abstractions. One way out is the next:

```
[AjaxOnly]
PartialViewResult GetViewAjax(int foo) { return GetView(foo); }
[ChildActionOnly]
PartialViewResult GetView(int foo) { ... }
```

But this is not neat at all.

---

The AjaxOnly attribute I am talking about is:

```
public sealed class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Public members

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This method is taken from MVC3 futures. An important comment why the condition is not `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` was made by dev team and says the following:

```
// Dev10 #939671 - If this attribute is going to say AJAX *only*, then we need to check the header
// specifically, as otherwise clients can modify the form or query string to contain the name/value
// pair we're looking for.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. Those 2 attributes are mutually exclusive. If an action is marked with `[ChildActionOnly]` it can never be directly accessed by the client using an HTTP request (be it synchronous or asynchronous). So if you want an action to ever be accessible using AJAX, you should never decorate it with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

I don't know what this `[AjaxOnly]` attribute is and where it comes from but depending on how it is implemented you might need to tweak it in order to allow child action requests if it relies only on the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method. For example if it is something like this:

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

you might want to tweak it like this:

```
public class AjaxOrChildActionOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && 
            !filterContext.IsChildAction
        )
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Suppose your action is re-used from different places both via RenderAction() and ajax requests. Suppose these are re-used on different pages as smth drawing some standard tool panel for many places and is used slightly different in different contexts

Comment: @Hohhi, so you want your action to be accessible only either through an AJAX call or as a Child action?

Comment: Exactly, Thank you for your suggestion, I would update the question and tell how far I get in some time

Comment: @Hohhi, well, that's exactly what my answer provides. An example of an `[AjaxOrChildActionOnly]` attribute that you could decorate your controller action with.

Comment: Thank you, I reuse it with two slight modification: 1) I changed the condition, 2) I throw on null filterContext

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and this answer was perfect for me. THX!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on Darin's answer and `ChildActionOnlyAttribute`'s source code, this is the solution I have come up with, which I think it's a tiny bit better:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AjaxOrChildAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.IsChildAction || controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

This way, the validation is done before even trying to execute, and the error you get if you type in the url is the exact same one as trying any invalid url.